# Create custom Django API response template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a response structure with django rest framework and have some standard template body:

Response body should have below parameters:

- status_code : It should accept status code and provide it as response
  object

  - Invalid entries: These are the invalid entrees made by user in the form and request did not process it.
  - Message: Should provide a success/failure message with details
  - Data: Json response data to front end
  - Anything which is blank should not go with response body.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Request you please put your code and what problem exactly you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably approaching the problem wrong way. You should use status code to pass information about success/failure, and then pass errors in data.

If you are using django rest framework, validation can be done by serializers:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

And then your view looks for example like

```
 def post(self, request):
    serializer = YourSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(**serializer.validated_data) 
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And then errors in data will look like this:

```
{
"email": [
    "Enter a valid email address."
],
"first_name": [
    "This field is required."
],
"last_name": [
    "This field is required."
],
"password": [
    "This field is required."
]
```

}

Comment: I am working on IOT, hence no database interactions for my APIs and hence I want a response template without serialized data